# Multi-way FunDeps and consistency with Overlapping Instances: (why) does this work?

Tags: haskell, functional-dependencies, overlapping-instances

This is a variation on an old chestnut. I wrote it expecting it not to work, but it did. Or is it dodgy? (At GHC 8.6.5.)

```
{-# LANGUAGE  MultiParamTypeClasses, FlexibleInstances, FlexibleContexts,
              FunctionalDependencies, UndecidableInstances, GADTs,
              PatternSignatures   #-}  -- deprecated, but we're not using ScopedTypeVariables

-- 3-way FunDep for Nats Add ??

data ZNat   = ZNat    deriving (Eq, Show, Read)
data SNat a = SNat a  deriving (Eq, Show, Read)

oneNat = SNat ZNat
twoNat = SNat oneNat

class AddNat a b c  | a b -> c, a c -> b, b c -> a  where  -- full 3 FunDeps
  addNat :: a -> b -> c

instance AddNat ZNat b b  where
  addNat _ y  = y

instance {-# OVERLAPPABLE #-} (a ~ SNat a', c ~ SNat c', AddNat a' b c')
         => AddNat a b c  where
  addNat (SNat x) y = SNat (addNat x y)

subNat (_ :: c) (_ :: b) = reflNat :: (AddNat a b c, ReflNat a) => a

-- test:
-- *Main> :t subNat twoNat oneNat
-- subNat twoNat oneNat :: SNat ZNat

class    ReflNat a          where reflNat :: a                -- for ref
instance ReflNat ZNat       where reflNat = ZNat
instance (ReflNat a') => ReflNat (SNat a')  where
  reflNat = (SNat (reflNat :: ReflNat aa => aa))
```

Traditionally there's only two FunDeps on class `AddNat`, and that second instance is

```
instance ( AddNat a' b c') 
         => AddNat (SNat a') b (SNat c')  where
  addNat (SNat x) y = SNat (addNat x y)            -- implementation is the same
```

That instance would get rejected `Functional dependencies conflict between instance declarations:` if there were FunDep `b c -> a`. As it is, the `OVERLAPPABLE` instance is exploiting GHC's [bogus FunDep consistency check](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/issues/10675#note_135395).

But without that FunDep, `subNat` can't infer its result from the arguments: `Ambiguous type variable 'a0'`. I'm guessing my test works because the types of the arguments to `subNat` are known in full. If they were partially known, type improvement would get stuck unable to reject the `ZNat b b` instance.

Oleg Kiselyov's ftp site used to have a class for 3-way improvement of adding naturals, but that had a complex rat's nest of auxiliary superclass constraints and auxiliary instances that essentially repeated the central class. What I've done seems too simplistic. Where will it go wrong?